# Can't understand laravel Mix works on my custom js/css files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm new to Laravel and whole framework stuff.

I do (may) understand a part of how the page rendered via laravel, but even after extensive search, I do not understand how laravel mix works.

Suppose that there is a page requires a global js and css library (lets specify jQuery and bootstrap)

Also the page requires custom js file like `someJsTools.js`.

Elementary speaking, in the past, those files referenced via `<script src="blah"></script>` and `<link rel="blah" />` inside `head` tag and I used to it. In this env, all I have to do is specify those tags page by page.

```
// pageA requires jQuery.js, bootstrap.css and one CUSTOM JS file imatrouble.js
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" herf="bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="imatrouble.js"></script>
</head>
```

---

```
//pageB requires jQuery.js, bootstrap.css and two custom js files.
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" herf="bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="imatrouble.js"></script>
    <script src="withimatroubleimadisasterlikewhateveryoucanimagine.js"></script>
</head>
```

`PageA` and `PageB` both requires common jQuery.js and bootstrap.css file. From what I learn, laravel Mix combine all js files into one and I don't get it here.

***Problem 1 - One file do everything?***
If it is true that "mix" things all together as one file, then how this one file could handle all of this different requirements seperatelly? I believe that my knowledge is wrong and its from my incorrect understanding of laravel mix and perhaps webpack mechanism.

***Problem 2 - How can I manage all different page and every different situation?***
Whether the problem above is originated from my missunderstanding or not, I cannot figure out what part of I (will) do could cause differences between pages. If mix only works for common global library, then all I have to do is just load custom js/css files manually. I currently assume that it is highly unlikely.

Please, someone help me to escape this chaos.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is purely based on your requirements. It depends on how you are customising your assets file.

For example :

Jquery, Angular,Bootstrap,Font Awesome is common for all your pages. So what I usually do is. I combine all css files to one file and all js files to one. Like below..

CSS mix

```
 elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        "libraries/bootstrap.css",
        "libraries/font-awesome.min.css",
        "custom/default.css",
    ], 'public/assets/css/common.css');
});
```

JS mix

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        "libraries/jquery-1.10.2.js",
        "libraries/bootstap.js"
        "libraries/angular.js",
        "libraries/angular-animate.js",
        "custom/defaut.js"
    ], 'public/assets/js/common.js');
});
```

Suppose some pages need specific dependency[product, orders...etc]. For instance if product page needs wow.js, product.js and wow.css,product.css

CSS mix

```
 elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        "libraries/wow.css",
        "custom/product.css",
    ], 'public/assets/css/product.css');
});
```

JS mix

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        "libraries/wow.js",
        "custom/product.js"
    ], 'public/assets/js/product.js');
});
```

So final laravel mix file looks like below

gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.sourcemaps = true;

/**
 * Global CSS MIX
 */
 elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        "libraries/bootstrap.css",
        "libraries/font-awesome.min.css",
        "custom/default.css",
    ], 'public/assets/css/common.css');
});

/**
 * Global JS MIX
 */
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        "libraries/jquery-1.10.2.js",
        "libraries/bootstap.js"
        "libraries/angular.js",
        "libraries/angular-animate.js",
        "custom/defaut.js"
    ], 'public/assets/js/common.js');
});

/**
 * Product CSS MIX
 */
 elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        "libraries/wow.css",
        "custom/product.css",
    ], 'public/assets/css/product.css');
});

/**
 * Product JS MIX
 */
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.scripts([
        "libraries/wow.js",
        "custom/product.js"
    ], 'public/assets/js/product.js');
});
```

Now all your assets files are ready. Now you need to include wherever you want.

Suppose on your homepage you only requires common.js and common.css files.

homepage.blade.php

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/common.css') }}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/css/common.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```

On the product page, you require both common and product assets file dependency. Include like below

product.blade.php

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/common.css') }}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/product.css') }}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/common.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/product.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks laktherock. I was thinking, there should be only one result file for any circumstances and its wrong.